# Как установить Magento 2 на виртуальный хостинг?

Tags: magento

Всем привет! Прочитал мануал на несколько раз. [ссылка на мануал](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/bk-install-guide.html) Залил архив в директорию public_html. Далее в браузере пишу адрес сайта и /setup/, но выдаётся ошибка 500. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Обратите внимание на [минимальные требования Magento 2](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/system-requirements.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php на сервере падает молча, потому вменяемой ошибки и не отдаётся.
Вероятные причины:

- неправильные права на файлы/каталоги (читать мануалы хостера, чтобы выставить правильно)
- устаревшая версия php (посмотреть в панели - а нельзя ли 5.6 выбрать)
- всё плохо с сервером

Если есть возможность посмотреть серверные логи ошибок (php, nginx), то будет больше информации. Как вариант - подключиться по ssh и запустить

```
php setup/index.php
```

может ругнётся в консоль чем-то осмысленным.

Для проверки третьего варианта - выложить файл 1.txt и попытаться его открыть.

Наиболее простой метод решения проблемы - общение с техподдержкой.

Comment: Вот в панели кстати выводится старая версия 5.3, а в настройках сайта можно поставить 5.6. К сожалению в панели нет nginx. Подключился по SHH, но тут честно скажу, опыта нет... Пробовал ввести команду "php setup.php/index.php", не сработала, зашёл в каталог и тоже не сработала. Первое обращение в поддержку, сказали, чтобы сам разбирался, написал, что по всей видимости всё сводится к настройке сервера, теперь жду, что ответят...

Comment: собственно magento ТРЕБУЕТ версии php посвежее...

Comment: Пообщался со службой поддержки, не смотря на то, что в админ-панели хостинга указано PHP 5.3, сказали, что сервер поддерживает 5.6. И это есть в настройке сайта, когда его создаешь выбираешь версию от 5.3 до 5.6.